# Windows Phone: Change title text to image in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i'm making a Panarama Windows Phone 8 App in Visual Studio 2013 and need to change the text to an image.

Any Ideas

Text:

[image]

Code:

```
 <!--Panorama control-->
    <phone:Panorama Title="my panorama">
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>
```

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: What's the question? What is "the text"?

Comment: You can't "change" it to an image.  What you can do is create a bitmap with tools like Paint or Paint.Net and "draw" text on them, save them, then add them to your project.

Comment: its ok i worked it out put the image on the PanoramaBackground.png and set Panorama Title="" Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: Panorama Title="" in the code.